# Help with ideas for framing around electrical panel

Tags: framing

Looking for ideas on how to frame around this panel, the internet board will be removed and placed on top of the finished drywall at a later time. the panel has a large inbound pvc pipe in the upper left that I'll have to figure out how to get around. this is non structural framing for a basement room.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's non-structural, so slap up some 2x4s, (or 2x3s) and remember to provide nail protection plates if you are going to run one over the big conduit.

Main advice - use removable, screwed in-place plywood (or whatever - backer board, perhaps, painted to match the wall) panels in the immediate vicinity of the panel so you can actually access the spaces around the panel for future wiring without breaking drywall.

Answer (score 2):

Good grief, the router and internet crud is *a lot* more unsightly than the electrical panel!

Just put the whole shebang behind a tasteful cabinet door.  Internet stuff also.

That would make the door 3-4 feet wide, but that is fine.

That's exactly what we did at the lodge, it vastly improves the room.

The trick is with covering an electrical panel, **electrical panels have required "working space"** that must be kept clear at all times.  Can't even stack boxes there, must be immediately available for a person to stand there and flick breakers off *frantically*.   The workspace must be the width of the panel (but at least 30"), 36" deep, and 78" (6'6") tall.  Or in Canada, all that rounded off in metric.

You need to keep that in mind when designing the cabinet/door.

Comment: ya it's a bit of a mess currently, the plan is to clean up the networking board quite a bit. I think just running a cabinet door is going to be the easiest thing for hiding away the panel.